# Any conjecture connecting almost $k$-primes and $k$-partitions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any conjecture or similar that suggests that almost $k$-prime can be partitioned into $k$ terms of which $k-1$ are composite and one prime or $k-2$ are composite and 2 prime?

Comment: By "almost $k$-prime", do you mean an integer with exactly $k$ prime factors counted with multiplicity? And by "partitioned" do you mean that the $k$ terms in the partition sum to the number?

Comment: yes k prime factors counted with multiplicity and k-terms in the sum partitions

Comment: This turns out not to be an interesting question. Once you allow one or more composites in the partition, it becomes super easy to add to the desired target. So it's easy, for example, to prove that all sufficiently large integers (regardless of their factorization) are the sum of $m$ composites and $n$ primes, for any fixed $m\ge1$ and $n\ge1$.

Comment: (a.b..n)-1= (a-1).1+ (b-1)a+ (c-1)a.b+.......+(n-1).a.b...(n-1)

Comment: (a.b..n)-1= (a-1).1+ (b-1)a+ (c-1)a.b+.......+(n-1).a.b...(n-1) derived this eqn imagining that a single rope can be cut by sequential cuts that add up to one less than number of final pieces of rope representing final product. Prof Martin please refer me to this analogy based derivation if you know where to find it. Thanks@GregMartin